# Matlab: Return multiple parameter values from a nlinfit (right now I only go through one index of the loop)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to pass three cell2mat arrays for I,V,H through this function and plot the result of the parameter from the nlinfit model below. But when the code is run it plots nothing and only stores one value. Any help is appreciated:)

```
function [Icp] = Fraunhofer_Function(I,V,H)        

V1 = @(b,I)(b(1).*sign(I).*real(sqrt(I.^2 - (sign(I).*(   (b(2)+b(3)/2)  )).^2)) + b(4));
Vthresx = find(V<=1e-3 & V>=0);
Ithresvec = max(I(Vthresx));

Voffsetx = find(I<=0.1e-3 & I>=-.1e-3);
Voffset = max(V(Voffsetx));

Rn =  (max(V)-min(V))/(max(I)-min(I));

beta1 = [Rn; Ithresvec; -Ithresvec; Voffset]; %Init values  b1=Rn b2 = Icp, b3 = Icm, b4 = Voffset
opts = statset('MaxIter', 500000, 'MaxFunEvals', 100000, 'RobustWgtFun', 'andrews');
B1 = nlinfit(I, V, V1, beta1, opts ); %Fit 
Icp = V1(B1,V);


end



  files = dir('*.xlsx*');
  for k =1:length(files)
  filenames = files(k).name;

  txt = 'I,V,H';
  [num,txt,raw] = xlsread(filenames);

  %Put data into numerical columns
  Idata = num(:,1)'; Vdata = num(:,2)'; Hdata = num(:,3)';        
  [Hu,~,idx] = unique(Hdata);
  Isplit = splitapply(@(x) {x}, [Idata(:)],idx);
  Vsplit = splitapply(@(x) {x}, [Vdata(:)],idx);
  Hsplit = splitapply(@(x) {x}, [Hdata(:)],idx);    

  for l = 1:length(Isplit)

      I = (Isplit{l,1});
      V = (Vsplit{l,1});
      H = (Hsplit{l,1});

     %fit the data to the functional form
      Icp = Fraunhofer_Function(I,V,H);              

  end
```

end

Example of the I,V,H, data is below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPfGi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are just setting `Icp` to the second estimated coefficient. From the Matlab docs [`nlinfit`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html#btk7ign-beta), the output `beta`:

> beta — Estimated regression coefficients
>   vector
>
> Estimated regression coefficients, returned as a vector. The number of elements in beta equals the number of elements in beta0.

So to use the estimated parameters, you should call your `modelfun`, with the parameters stored in `B1`:

```
Icp = V1(B1,V);
plot(H,Icp);
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense.

Comment: So, your answer is correct, but I have a separate question--and have updated the question above

Comment: just store the result of the function in a vector or cell array: `Icp{l} = Fraunhofer_Function`, and then make a separate loop to plot the the various data. You didn't show any plotting code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529460/indexing-through-nlinfit-in-a-seperate-script-only-returns-one-fitted-set-of-val